# setProgressDrawable fills the entire seekBar

Tags: android, progress-bar, progress, seekbar, fill

As I say in the title, when I use setProgressDrawable, it fills the entire SeekBar: if progress is at 34%, progress show 100% but thumb shows the correct percentatge 34%. I don't figure out what can be the problem...

```
   done.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seekbar_progress));
   done.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seekbar_thumb));
```

seekbar_progress.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
<stroke android:width="15dp"    android:color="#52a8ec"/>
```

seekbar_thumb.xml

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:startColor="#ffffffff" android:endColor="#ff585858" android:angle="270"/>
<size android:height="17dp" android:width="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you add some code how you are trying to do

Answer (score 8):

try to put the fill shape inside a clip tag like so

```
<clip>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
<stroke android:width="15dp"    android:color="#52a8ec"/>
</clip>
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, thanks, and I think is a better answer as it's all within the custom progress bar XML rather than adding code.

Comment: This solution worked for me. But I don't know how it works. Please explain to understand better.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and the following code resolved it.

Wherever you are using the code to change your drawable just do the following (where 'p' is your seekbar) :

```
int currentProgress = p.getProgress();
p.setProgress(0);
Rect bounds = p.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
p.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_drawable_orange));
p.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);
p.setProgress(currentProgress);
```

and do not forget to add the following check in your `onProgressChanged`
method:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if(!fromUser)
        return;
    // ... THE REST OF YOUR CODE
}
```

[example](http://mytechead.wordpress.com/category/android/)

Comment: still fills the entire progress bar for me :(

Answer (score 1):

I ended in the same situation as you did and managed to resolve the problem by implementing progress with layer-list XML file.
See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10615806/731314).

Comment: I've copyied and pasted all your xml files and it stills filling the entire seekbar...

Comment: Some people suggest that after calling setProgressDrawable() method, SeekBar needs to be redrawn.
Try setting the padding, incrementing progress etc.
My code afterwards is:
   seekBar.setThumb(d);
   seekBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
   seekBar.setProgress(0);
   seekBar.setThumbOffset(-1);
   seekBar.setMax((int) (max - min));

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the `progressTint` field in your layout xml to change the progress color without affecting the SeekBar's entire background.

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressTint="@color/seek_bar_progress"/>
```

There's also `thumbTint` and `progressBackgroundTint`.