# How to draw Line with rounded corners in Android xml drawables

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I want to draw a line in the `XML` with rounded corners.I am not getting how to create that.I want to use this line for the `Seekbar`. I want to give rounded corners to the line just like rectangle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="5dp"
            android:color="#7b7878" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
    //seek_bar.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_background"/>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_progress" />
</layer-list>

//seek_bar_background.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:startColor="#8a8c8f"
    android:endColor="#58595b" />

<corners android:radius="5dip" />

</shape>

//seek_bar_progress.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_background"/>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_progress_fill" />
</item>

</layer-list>

//seek_bar_progress_fill.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<gradient
    android:startColor="#b3d27e"       
    android:endColor="#93c044"
    android:angle="270"
 />
 <corners android:radius="5dip" />  

</shape>
```

[Ref link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10615806/3374796)

Comment: and where are you want to use this drawable image

Comment: i want to use it for the `SeekBar` progress line.

Comment: after using this drawable you can do it because it's showing rounded corner and if you wan to increase size of corner then increase number of radius PARAM

Answer (score 1):

You need to setStrokeCap() to Paint.Cap.ROUND