# Setting progress drawable on Seekbar causes thumb to overflow

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a problem with `seekbars`. They work without issues until I try and do the following:

```
seekBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seek_bar));
```

I even tried using a color only instead of a `drawable` resource. Same issue. The problem is when I do set the `drawable`, I see that the `Seekbar` drawable is a bit shorter (from start and end) and the thumb icon can go beyond it.

Also, I have noticed that the thumb icon itself has a white background surrounding it (not transparent). I even tried setting a vector drawable for the thumb, and the thumb went beyond the boundaries of seekbar (part of the thumb was hidden).

Could someone explain this behavior. I have tried searching for around three hours now without luck. I even tried the solution from:

[How to set Android SeekBar progress drawable programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536202/how-to-set-android-seekbar-progress-drawable-programatically)

Which has the same issue for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the non-transparent background I have used:

```
seekBar.setSplitTrack(false);
```

To make the thumb not go beyond the boundaries, I have shrunk the thumb. It is not perfect but it works.